# iOS MDM - App com.xxx.xxxx is already scheduled for management

Tags: ios, mdm

I'm setting up an MDM installation to distribute apps to supervised devices and seem to regularly get the managed application into a weird state where it's "scheduled for management" but doesn't actually install to the device. It's unclear to me how it gets into that state or how to get it out of that state.

I tried to use the RemoveApplication command, but since it never actually installed, this failed to remove it. I was able to get it out of this state by turning the device off and letting it forget it's volatile memory and then turning it back on, but this is an unacceptable solution for the use case I'm trying to achieve.  It also doesn't seem to always fix the issue.

I attempted to use a support ticket with Apple to resolve this, but they basically told me that the problem we're experiencing should be submitted as a bug report, so we submitted that to them.

Basically, I'm just wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue and if you have, do you know of any workarounds to get it out of this state?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an app from the app store?

Comment: It isn't.  It's an enterprise app that is being developed in parallel with our MDM solution.

Comment: Your question doesn't state clearly--does the app eventually work after your described workaround?

Comment: It sometimes does work eventually, but the devices we're managing will be difficult to get at, so I don't think that that workaround really works for us.